# How to prevent intermittent error "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'" while updating many files in Share Point location?

Tags: python, sharepoint

I have written a python script to update 90 files in a Share Point location.

Code snippet -

```
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.runtime.auth.client_credential import ClientCredential
from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File

def getSharePointContext(site_url,username,password):
   ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(site_url)
   if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(username, password):
      ctx = ClientContext(site_url, ctx_auth)

def writeFile(fileUrl,fileName):
   # read past data
   readCtx=getSharePointContext(fileUrl,usernameSP,passwordSP)
   resData = File.open_binary(readCtx, fileUrl)
   bytes_file_obj = io.BytesIO()
   bytes_file_obj.write(resData.content)
   bytes_file_obj.seek(0)
   pastData=pd.read_csv(bytes_file_obj)
   #...code to get new data
   # update dataframe
   # dfResult - variable contains pastData and newData merged together
   #write updated data
   target_folder = baseCtx.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_url(f"Shared 
                         Documents/{relPath}")
   buffer = io.BytesIO()
   dfResult.to_csv(buffer, index=False)
   buffer.seek(0)
   file_content = buffer.read()
   target_folder.upload_file(fileName, file_content).execute_query()


if __name__ == '__main__':
   # set context to base URL and use it to write all files
   baseCtx=getSharePointContext(sharePointUrl,usernameSP,passwordSP)
   # ....code....
   for fileName,fileUrl in files.items():
       writeFile(filename,fileUrl)
```

When I run the script for 90 files in one go, I get an intermittent error for the 70th or 71st file, often. But when I run the script for 2 files, I get no error.

Error -

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException', 'The security validation for this page has timed out. Click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and try your operation again.
```

Kindly advise me regarding the correct approach to avoid this sort of error while updating many files.

Comment: Is your file too large, maybe it needs to be uploaded separately?